# Why am I getting cannot overwrite directory error while trying to do mvn package install?

Tags: java, maven, apache-pinot

I am using below command in windows 11, using git bash.

`mvn install package -DskipTests -Pbin-dist -Drat.numUnapprovedLicenses=1000 -Dcheckstyle.skip -rf :pinot-distribution`

[Here is pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/pinot/blob/master/pom.xml)

I am getting following error. Can someone please help?

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.1:single (binary-release-assembly-pinot) @ pinot-distribution ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: pinot-assembly.xml
[INFO] Building tar: C:\GitHubProjects\pinot\pinot-distribution\target\apache-pinot-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz
[INFO] Copying files to C:\GitHubProjects\pinot\pinot-distribution\target\apache-pinot-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin
[WARNING] Assembly file: C:\GitHubProjects\pinot\pinot-distribution\target\apache-pinot-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin is not a regular file (it may be a directory). It cannot be attached to the project build for installation or deployment.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (create-build-directory) @ pinot-distribution ---
/usr/bin/ln: 'C:\GitHubProjects\pinot\pinot-distribution/../build/apache-pinot-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin': cannot overwrite directory
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
```

Comment: *apache-pinot-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin is not a regular file (it may be a directory)* remove it by hand and try again

Comment: I tried removing directory manually from build/apache-pinot-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin folder, the error is still same.

Comment: You should remove it from the folder mentioned in the error message

Comment: I see this as folder ../build/apache-pinot-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin, I did try removing apache-pinot-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to the [POM](https://github.com/apache/pinot/blob/master/pom.xml) you attached, it is composed of a bunch of modules, and the one where the problem is, seems to be the `pinot-distribution` one, and this is its [POM](https://github.com/apache/pinot/blob/master/pinot-distribution/pom.xml):

```
<module>pinot-distribution</module>
```

**The [WARNING]**

As it can be seen in the logs you put, the execution that fails is `binary-release-assembly-pinot`. Guess that you are trying to create an assembly with the `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin, whose description is depicted in the [pinot-assembly.xml](https://github.com/apache/pinot/blob/master/pinot-distribution/pinot-assembly.xml) file.

The problem I see here (the XML file) is that you are trying to create several assemblies:

```
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
```

And the second one is suspicious (seems that the idea is just create a `tar.gz` file).

> Above this snippet you can see another usage of this
> `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin, named as
> `source-release-assembly-pinot`, whose assembly descriptor file is
> [pinot-source-assembly.xml](https://github.com/apache/pinot/blob/master/pinot-distribution/pinot-source-assembly.xml), and looks like well formed.

**The [ERROR]**

After that, going back to the [pinot-distribution POM](https://github.com/apache/pinot/blob/master/pinot-distribution/pom.xml), there is another execution, with id `create-build-directory`, where you are trying to create a symbolic link (command `ln -sfn`), within the directory

```
${project.basedir}/../build
```

So you have to consider where this directory is created / used, or maybe just not forcing it (`-f`), because it involves overwriting it.

Comment: I commented entire create-build-directory and it worked fine.

Comment: I believe this is because of my Windows OS, since I tried same thing in Linux and it worked without any issues.